# Is it possible to convert a UTexture2D to an OpenCV::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, unreal-engine4, mat, texture2d

I am an developer that works with plugin development for unreal (C++), and I have been tasked with integrating openCV into unreal engine for a project. I was able to handle getting the std:: issues solved, but I am stuck and frustrated with trying to get a UTexture2D to be converted into an opencv::Mat. I have a C++ function that takes in a UTexture2D* and needs to use openCV to manipulate it. To do this, it must be converted to an opencv::Mat. I tried doing pixel-to-pixel conversion, but it crashes every time or hangs. Any guide on how to do this necessary conversion is greatly appreciated, thanks!

I have tried a few versions of this code with no success, but this is my latest failure:

```
//obtain all the pixel information from the mipmaps
FTexture2DMipMap* MyMipMap = &MyTexture2D->PlatformData->Mips[0];
FByteBulkData* RawImageData = &MyMipMap->BulkData;

//store in fcolor array
uint8* Pixels = static_cast<uint8*>(RawImageData->Lock(LOCK_READ_ONLY));

//trying via constructor
cv::Mat myImg = cv::Mat( 3000, 1100, CV_8UC3);

//trying to map the pixels individually
for (int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int32 x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int32 curPixelIndex = ((y * width) + x);
        myImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = Pixels[4 * curPixelIndex];
        myImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = Pixels[4 * curPixelIndex + 1];
        myImg.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = Pixels[4 * curPixelIndex + 2];
    }
};

//unlock thread
RawImageData->Unlock();
```

Comment: Could you share a code snippet so we get a glimpse of  your code that crashes?

Comment: yep, added the most recent code I tried!

Comment: cv::Mat has various constructors. one of them takes a pointer to data (and width, height, element type). the pointer is kept inside the cv::Mat (it will not allocate/free its own memory, it will use the pointer instead). your data has a stride of 4 bytes, so you should use CV_8UC4. *please work with the documentation. it contains tutorials.* BTW: "unreal developer" implies that you work on the unreal engine itself. I suspect however that you are a user of the engine/library.

Comment: `at()` takes **row first, then column**.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I elaborated in response to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use correct constructor of `cv::Mat` that takes a data pointer. That Mat object will not allocate or free its own memory. It will use the memory it was given. Such a Mat will not be resizable and it will only be valid as long as the given memory is okay to access.

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a

```cpp
...
uint8* Pixels = ...;

cv::Mat myImg { height, width, CV_8UC4, Pixels };
// myImg is now usable

// access pixels like so: myImg.at<Vec4b>(y,x)

...
```

This example uses uniform initialization. "Old" styles are okay too.

Comment: Code was changed to reflect this notation, and the image still hangs upon accessing the image after creation (methods for accessing imshow, dilate, etc) ('hangs' is defined as the process containing opencv being non-responsive and orphaned upon the main process exiting). Also, I know the array is using 4 bytes per pixel since unreal contains an alpha layer. I was ignoring that byte in the loop, hence the Vec3b. As far as the rows and columns being swapped, that one is on me.

Comment: The behavior is intermittent, as upon running it a few more times it finally dilated the image without hanging. I'm thinking there is a memory leak elsewhere in the spawning process. Either way, thanks for your help!